# Should I use `__setattr__`, a property or...?

Tags: python

I have an object with two attributes, `file_path` and `save_path`. Unless `save_path` is explicitly set, I want it to have the same value as `file_path`.

I *think* the way to do this is with `__setattr__`, with something like the following:

```
class Class():
...
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'file_path':
            self.file_path = value
            self.save_path = value if self.save_path == None else self.save_path
        elif name == 'save_path':
            self.save_path = value
```

But this looks like it's going to give me infinite loops since `__setattr__` is called whenever an attribute is set. So, what's the proper way to write the above and avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this looks kind of unpythonic.  You can just use attributes.  Three lines of code:

```
>>> class Class:
...     def __init__(self, file_path, save_path=None):
...         self.file_path=file_path
...         self.save_path = save_path or file_path
... 
>>> c = Class('file')
>>> c.file_path
'file'
>>> c.save_path
'file'

>>> c1 = Class('file', 'save')
>>> c1.file_path
'file'
>>> c1.save_path
'save'
>>>
```

Comment: If you can avoid needing `save_path` and `file_path` to be mutable, something like this is probably the way to go. If they do need to be mutable, it doesn't work so well.

Comment: I was having the same type of thought, but less organized. The above doesn't seem to account for initiating with a `file_path` and not a `save_path`, then later updating the `file_path`. Perhaps I don't need that use case, I'll have to think about it.

Comment: @Chuck I took your question to mean that you will always have file_path, but only sometimes save_path.  If you have one or the other, it would be easy to set each to what you have.  But what if you have neither?  Then you could set them to some default

Comment: Currently, by default, they're both `None`, but this is making me re-think that. It may be that having an instance without at least a `file_path` makes no sense.

Comment: I chose this one after rethinking a bit, and making `file_path` required cleaned up the class code in a few other ways too.

Answer (score 9):

First, the easiest way to do this would be with a property:

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self._save_path = None
        ...
    @property
    def save_path(self):
        if self._save_path is None:
            return self.file_path
        else:
            return self._save_path
    @save_path.setter
    def save_path(self, val):
        self._save_path = val
```

Second, if you ever find yourself needing to write a `__setattr__`, you should use `super(Class, self).__setattr__` inside your `__setattr__` to bypass your `__setattr__` and set attributes the normal way, avoiding infinite recursion.

Comment: great job! You fixed this a second before I hit _Add Comment_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `super`!

```
class Class:                                                           
    def __init__(self):                                                
        self.save_path = None                                          
        self.file_path = None                                          

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):                                
        super().__setattr__(name, value)                               
        if name == 'file_path':                                        
            super().__setattr__('save_path', self.save_path or value)  

c = Class()                                                            
c.file_path = 42                                                       
print(c.file_path)                                                     
print(c.save_path)
```

Note that there's a limitation to this *particular* implementation - `self.save_path` needs to be called first, or it's going to fail because it hasn't been set yet when the call to `super` happens and it looks for `self.save_path or value`.

I would probably use the property based approach, personally.

Comment: This ends up not quite working, because it can't distinguish between an explicitly set `save_path` and one implicitly set by setting `file_path`. If you set `file_path` twice, `save_path` will retain the first value.

Comment: Ah. Well, if *that* is part of your requirement, then you'd need `__getattr__` too. Or to use the property based approach, which is a lot cleaner